# Divergence in local coordinates

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

I'm working on an electrostatics problem and I'd like to find out what the divergence is in a weird coordinate system.

The problem is a cone with a fixed charge.

In the attached image, you can see that $x$ is the distance along the cone and $y$ is the distance normal to the cone.

Everything is axisymmetric about the red line.

My question is, what is the divergence in terms of $x$ and $y$ and PHI ($\phi$)? Thanks.

[image: coordinates]

Comment: Is this in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: I'm solving for a vector field E in R^3

Comment: Then I don't understand your drawing very well. Did you get this from a book or something like that?

Comment: No, so I have drawn the cone. I now want to solve for a vector/potental field in the space outside the cone. This is a 2D cross section. Everything is rotated around the red line.

Comment: Spherical coordinates would serve you just as well, and the divergence in that system is well-known. Basically, instead of $x$, you'd have $\rho$, and instead of $\phi$, you'd have the polar angle. Once you found what you were looking for, you could use the usual transformations to get your $y$.

Comment: To talk about divergence in terms of $x, y, \phi$, you need them to be a coordinate system. That is, in some neighborhood of a point, $(x, y, \phi)$ should be a 1-1 mapping onto an open set in $\Bbb R^3$. But this is not the case. $\phi$ and $y$ provide coverage in the same direction. For any point $p$, there are a continuum of ways to express it by trading off between $\phi$ and $y$. On the other hand, there is nothing that measures angle about the $z$ axis. So any value of $x, y, \phi$ corresponds to a circle of points. Are you sure you have described $\phi$ correctly?